# What's with the missing thumbs in "The Road"?

Tags: the-road

I've only seen the film *The Road*, I haven't read the books.  Perhaps I missed it, but what was going on with the people missing their thumbs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[According to the director](http://archive.is/fpRsm#selection-863.4-863.113) (who's paraphrasing the author of the book) it's "open to interpretation, I think some kind of primitive punishment..."

Answer (score 6):

You can find the answer in the book, when *the man* and *the boy* went after the man who stole their cart:

> Get away from the cart, the man said.
>
> He looked at them. He looked at
>   the boy. **He was an outcast from one of the communes and the fingers of
>   his right hand had been cut away**. He tried to hide it behind him. **A
>   sort of fleshy spatula**. The cart was piled high. He’d taken
>   everything.
>
> Get away from the cart and put down the knife.
>
> ~ Cormac McCarthy’s *The Road*, page 273 (Picador, London, 2007)

It was a punishment for leaving (or being kicked out of) a commune.

There's a wonderful thread discussing the different approaches and theories regarding the missing thumbs **[here](https://thepoplartree.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/a-few-thoughts-on-missing-thumbs-in-cormac-mccarthy%E2%80%99s-the-road/)**.